# ¿Es posible apaisar una hoja en un informe r markdown con salida pdf? (R studio)

Tags: r, r-markdown

Tengo una tabla gt muy larga, si pongo el nombre del objeto (tabla gt) no me lo toma, por lo que opté por hacer un gtsave() y luego leer desde el rmd con esta función knitr::include_graphics("imag/gt3.png") pero aun así me corta la tabla

Hay alguna posibilidad de apaisar (hacer horizontal) una sola hoja del rmd con salida pdf?

Comment: Hola Romina, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código y los mensajes de error (si es que los recibes) en formato texto, y que nos expliques en que falla, mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!